# Getting database ID of objects in ListView and updating ListView from user control ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am creating a website and am facing the following problem. I have 2  ListViews.
The first ListView is inside a user control called Sidebar.ascx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="sidebarListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSidebar">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <div class="sidebarItem" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
     </div>
  </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <LayoutTemplate>
  <div class="sidebarMain">
     <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
  </div>
 </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceSidebar" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TudengiDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name] FROM [Faculties] ORDER BY [Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It has to display only the name.

The second listview is inside my Default.aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:ListView ID="RecentItemsListView" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
        GroupItemCount="3">
        <LayoutTemplate>
           <div class="recentItemsMain">
              <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder" />
           </div>
           <asp:DataPager ClientIDMode="Static" ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="9">
              <Fields>
                 <asp:NumericPagerField />
              </Fields>
           </asp:DataPager>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
           <div class="recentItems">
              <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
           </div>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="recentItem" runat="server">
              <div>
                 <asp:Image ID="PictureThumb" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#CreateThumbnail((string)Eval("Picture"),130,130) %>' />
              </div>
              <asp:Label ID="AuthorLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Author") %>' />
              <div>
                 <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
              </div>
           </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
           <div class="groupSeparator">
           </div>
        </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
     </asp:ListView>

  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TudengiDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Id], [Name], [Faculty_Id], [User_Id], [Author], [Picture], [Location] FROM [Books] ORDER BY [DateAdded] DESC">
```

What I need is for the  ListView in Default.aspx to display the data without a WHERE clause, but when an item is clicked in the Sidebar user control I need to update the Default.aspx ListView to display only the data where the [Faculty_Id] = the ID of the  ListView item in the user control.

How can I get the database ID of the  ListView object when I can only display the NAME field? Do I have to display the ID as well and then hide the column from users?
What is the correct way to solve a situation like this?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:ListView ID="sidebarListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceSidebar" OnItemCommand="sidebarListView_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="sidebarItem" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
     </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This is what I ended up with.

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. Answering your own question (and documenting your efforts) is encouraged in SO.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, but it says "You can accept your answer in 2 days". So that's when I'm doing it:)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add an attribute to the `NameLabel` control.
Call it for example `myID`:

```
<asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' myID='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
```

then access that attribute from your code to get your ID:

```
string ID = NameLabel.Attributes["myID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden-field to your item-template to hold the database ID.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnFacultyID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FacultyID") %>' />
   <div class="recentItem" runat="server">
   ...
   </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

In the appropriate ListView handlers, you can access the database ID something like this.

```
((HiddenField)e.item.FindControl("hdnFacultyID")).Value
```